# SQL Server Express with Hangfire connect problem : login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express, hangfire

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server Express in my `Hangfire service`.

Code in my `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
            .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
            .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
            .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                UsePageLocksOnDequeue = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            }));

        services.AddHangfireServer();
```

Based on documentation, Hangfire 1.7 have `built ib sql query` to create database.

I make default connection string from docs:

```
"HangfireConnection": "Server=.\\sqlexpress; Database=Hangfire; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

But when I run my app, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "Hangfire" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-FOVJ16Q\Michal'

My `Security` tab from SQL Server Express looks like this:

[image]

Could you tell me, what can I check to make connection with my SQL Server Express?

**EDIT1**

My SQL Server Express "Security" tab with `Logins`:

[image]

My `DESKTOP-FOVJ16Q\Micha` properties:

[image]

**EDIT2**

I checked for now, from that connection string:

```
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TaskManager;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

I can simply make database in my `SQL Express` and look on it in `Management studio`

Comment: Check two things: **(1)** is there a **login** for this Windows user `DESKTOP-FOVJ16Q\Michal` in your SQL Server Express instance? And **(2)** is there a user in your `Hangfire` database that refers to that login ?

Comment: @marc_s look at my edit, i showed u my `desktop` user credentials. `Hangfire` database is not even created, because `login failed` of sql express

Comment: Give `DESKTOP-FOVJ16Q\Michal` `sysadmin` privileges, and GRANT connect to SQL, and you should be set. (note, sometimes you need to run the application (or visualstudio) as an Administrator).

Comment: @marc_s based on `Hangfire` documentation, database in newest version creat on is own: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html.

Comment: @iSR5 i give for `desktop` user all priviliges. Byd efault it was `sysadmin` and `Grant` connect

Comment: @marc_s i dont know if it is `sql server` problem, `connection string` or `Hangfire` problem, because i have on my local machine existing databases on this `sql server`

Comment: @michasaucer the letter `L` in Michal is not an English letter. Retype the username in your SQL, make sure you're using English Letters. Match that in your code, and you should be able to solve it. If not solved, delete the user and recreate it manually, ensuring the username it's all english letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the comments on that page you linked to (https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html), you'll find a question by "Fabian Schneiter" who asks pretty much the same question as you did - and got this response:

> You need to create the database `Hangfire` on your server first.. I understood, that hangfire will create the DB too, **but that's wrong**. If you have a Hangfire DB, Hangfire will create all needed tables..

So my recommendation: try **creating** the `Hangfire` database as a new database - then run your code again and see if it works

Comment: I make simple query: `Create Database Hangfire` and project compiles. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a static method to generate all needs databases in first Run.

```cs
public static void Generate(string databasename)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCreator"].ConnectionString; ;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    
    string sql = string.Format(
            @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'{0}')
                BEGIN
                    create database [{0}]  
                END;",
            databasename);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

and its connection string is :

```
<add name="DBCreator" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=True;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in Startup file before Hangfire first I create DB:

```
DataBaseGenerator.Generate("Hangfire");
```